# post login operation with j_security_check

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish-3, j-security-check

I am using form-based authentication and j_security_check in my j2ee application which runs on glassfish 3.1.
Problem is when login succeed I have to update some data related to authenticated user. 
How to make post-login operation after j_security_check ends it's execution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround with Servlet 3.0 (or Java EE 6): Call [`HttpServletRequest.login()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) from a managed bean and if it doesn't throw an exception do your post login operations.

Comment: There is allways simple solution for everything :) Thanks!

Comment: what if I'm bounded by Java EE 5 only?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a filter which is mapped to `j_security_check`
2. You need to overwrite the `Origin` header of the response before `chain.doFilter(request, response);` of that filter and also to place your post redirect URL in the cookie `WASReqURL` (Or the cookie of glassfish that holds the next url)
3. The link you chose in step 2 need to be mapped to a servlet which executes the post-j_security_check stuff and afterward, to redirect back to the overwritten link from step 2.

Comment: 1. Can you really catch requests to j_security_check in i Filter? Shouldn't JAAS catch those requests and not let them through to the servet?

Comment: yes, but this filter will be before starting the authentication validation. Therefore, assuming anything about the credentials like adding data to session is wrong approach.